# Best practices for Domain Service classes in RIA Silverlight projects

Tags: silverlight, data-access-layer, wcf-ria-services

I would like to ask whether or not is a good practice, to hold the *CRUD* operations for business objects, in a single domain service class. Should we provide a domain service class for each BO?

ProductDomainService.cs
CustomerDomainService.cs
...

or a single

BusinessObjectDomainService.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with a single domain object beause my model is not that complex.  I would think it might be better to cluster the domain services together ie user services logging services.  That kind of logical clumping would be better than 1 for each business object.